# Cleaning up a list that contains other lists casted to strings

Tags: python, string, list

How do I get the list `before` to look like `after`?

```
before = ['Vicente, Piura, Perú', 'Escobar, Buenos Aires, Argentina', "['San Juan, Argentina', 'California, Estados Unidos de América']"]

after = ['Vicente, Piura, Perú', 'Escobar, Buenos Aires, Argentina', 'San Juan, Argentina', 'California, Estados Unidos de América']
```

There's a list within a list that is cast to a string

Comment: What problem are you struggling with? Iterating over a list to change some elements but not others? Identifying whether a string contains the text representation of a list? Turning that text representation into a list? Also, in your example the list contains other strings - is that always true? Where is the data coming from - could you have avoided this problem easily, and if not, can the data be trusted 100% or does the conversion be careful to avoid injection problems? What have you tried yourself? Have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea upvotes of the comment not withstanding - that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

A solution:

```
# if you have any control over the system that gives you this list,
# you should probably fix that instead
before = [
    'Vicente, Piura, Perú',
    'Escobar, Buenos Aires, Argentina',
    "['San Juan, Argentina', 'California, Estados Unidos de América']"
]

# however, string representations of a list all start with [ and end with ]
# if you trust the source of the data, you could consider using ast.literal_eval()
import ast
after = [x for xs in [
    ast.literal_eval(s) if s and s[0] == '[' and s[-1] == ']' else [s] for s in before
] for x in xs]
print(after)
# note: the `s and` bit makes sure empty strings don't cause trouble
```

Note: you want to use `ast.literal_eval()` in this case, not `eval()` which is much unsafer and unneeded here. `eval()` would allow all sorts of arbitrary code to be executed, and if some other program is responsible for the text input, you could be in serious trouble.

[More on ast.literal_eval() here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Output:

```
['Vicente, Piura, Perú', 'Escobar, Buenos Aires, Argentina', 'San Juan, Argentina', 'California, Estados Unidos de América']
```

However, if you were tasked with this as part of a programming course, this is probably not what they were looking for. The data has some interesting gotchas:

- in the example, the outer quotes are double quotes, and the inner ones are single; could that be reversed?
- can the text in the string representation of the list also contain quotes, that would be escaped? What about commas and brackets?
- will the string representation of the list always be a valid representation, or can it contain syntax errors?

Depending on the answers to these questions, something like a regex may become very hard to write (nevermind understand or maintain) and you may need to do more involved parsing on the strings that appear to contain a list.

Comment: I'm just noticing the separation but this can be done without a loop or list comprehension

Comment: If you have such a solution, feel free to post an answer - your comment has nothing to do with the answer I provided. (and I disagree with it regardless)

Comment: Check it out I just posted it

Answer (score 0):

Another method to suggest is using json, but you need to make a simple change in the input string by adding double quotes instead of single quotes

```
before = [
    'Vicente, Piura, Perú',
    'Escobar, Buenos Aires, Argentina',
    '["San Juan, Argentina", "California, Estados Unidos de América"]'
]
import json
after = []
for word in before:
    after.extend(json.loads(word)) if '[' in word and ']' in word else after.append(word)
print(after)
```

**Output**

```
['Vicente, Piura, Perú', 'Escobar, Buenos Aires, Argentina', 'San Juan, Argentina', 'California, Estados Unidos de América']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the extra brackets and then split regarding to the ','. At the end append this created list to what we have

```
before = ['Vicente, Piura, Perú', 'Escobar, Buenos Aires, Argentina', "['San Juan, Argentina', 'California, Estados Unidos de América']"]
modified_string = before[2][1:-1]
modified_list = modified_string.split(', ')
after = before[:2] + modified_list
print(after)
```

Comment: Try running this with OP's data - it doesn't work, since there's also `', '` inside the string values in the string representation of the list.